# Validation does not seem to be working on my laravel project

Tags: laravel

i tried validating fields using validator. but it doesnt working. the error message is not showing in the .
This is my controller

```
$validator = Validator::make(
            $request->all(),
            [
                'b_name' => 'required|max:20',
            ],
            [
                'b_name.required' => 'please fill this field',

            ]
        );
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return Response::make([
                'message' => trans('validation failed'),
                'errors' => $validator->errors(),
            ]);
        }
```

and this is my blade

```
 <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="Building" class="control-label">Building<sup class="mandatory">*</sup></label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="b_name" id="b_name" value=""required="true" aria-required="true" />
                    <div class="help-block b_name-error"></div>
                  </div>
```

this field is is in a modal. is there any chance it isnt working because of the modal.

Comment: `dd($request->all())` and post the results plz.

Comment: array:3 [
  "id" => null
  "b_name" => null
  "b_description" => null
]

Comment: where are you expecting this error message to show? "the error message is not showing in the ."  ... missing a word there

Comment: i want to show errors below each field.

Comment: what is missing there?

Answer (score 1):

You're returning the error in response but in blade file there is no any error message to display.

```
if ($validator->fails()) {
  return redirect()->back()->withErrors(['msg', $validator->errors()->first()]); 
}
```

Now get this error as below.

```
@if($errors->any())
<h4>{{$errors->first()}}</h4>
@endif
```